# Python - Determine overlaps of 3 ranges

Tags: python, range, overlap

I had a question regarding how I should go about determining overlaps of three ranges in Python without using any existing libraries :

For instance if I have three ranges as (10,20)(15,25)(18,30), how should I go about finding overlaps between them ?

My answer should be (18,19,20)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Also, what do you mean by those given ranges? A range object in Python (`range(10, 20)`) goes to less than the second value, not including, so the expected output would be `(18, 19)`.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953967/built-in-function-for-computing-overlap-in-python)

Comment: @Steve Not a duplicate, that question asks for specifically **two** ranges, while this question asks for **three**. While it's easy to extrapolate out, it's not a duplicate. Obviously, a general answer (as given here) is a better option.

Answer (score 8):

The overlap goes from the highest start point to the lowest end point:

```
ranges = [(10,20), (15,25), (18,30)]
starts, ends = zip(*ranges)
result = range(max(starts), min(ends) + 1)
```

Test:

```
>>> print(*result)
18 19 20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I have many such ranges (about a million of them). i.e there are 3 ranges, but there are about million such comparisons to make. 
Could you tell me a computationally fast method of comparing million such ranges.

Comment: It takes about 2 seconds on my PC. Unless you are actually creating the ranges as lists (using Python 2.x and not using `xrange`, for example) **and** the results are **huge** this will be fast. If you have to create the actual lists and they are huge, no method will help.

Answer (score 4):

While [WolframH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761869/722121) is the best answer for this case, a more general solution for finding overlaps is available, given you don't need to worry about repeated elements, which is to use sets and their `intersection` operation.

```
>>> set(range(10, 21)) & set(range(15, 26)) & set(range(18, 31))
{18, 19, 20}
```

Or, as a more general solution:

```
ranges = [(10, 20), (15, 25), (18, 30)]
set.intersection(*(set(range(start, finish+1)) for start, finish in ranges))
```

Comment: Nice, and you don't even need `reduce`: `set.intersection(*(set(range(start, finish+1)) for start, finish in ranges))`.

Comment: @WolframH Nice, I did not know that `set.intersection()` accepted multiple sets, that's awesome. I always feel dirty whenever I have to resort to `reduce()`. Edited.