# Finding range overlap between at least three ranges Python

Tags: python, range, overlap

I have a list of tuples, which I am using to mark the lower and upper bounds of ranges. For example:

```
[(3,10), (4,11), (2,6), (8,11), (9,11)] # 5 separate ranges.
```

I want to find the ranges where three or more of the input ranges overlap. For instance the tuples listed above would return:

```
[(4,6), (8,11)]
```

I tried the method provided by @WolframH in answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761833/python-determine-overlaps-of-3-ranges)

But I don't know what I can do to:

- Give me more than one output range
- Set a threshold of at least three range overlaps to qualify an output

Comment: Shouldn't that second tuple be `(8,11)`?  Also, will the ranges always be bounded by integers?

Comment: @Brionius yes it should. I'll just edit that now.

Comment: I think it should be (9,11)
range(8,11)  =  [8,9,10] and this is only included in range(4,11) and range(8,11)

Comment: As far as I can tell from 8-9 you get overlap from (3,10), (4,11), and (8,11). And then from 9-10 you get overlap from (4,11), (8,11) and (9,11). This covers 8, 9 and 10 giving a range of (8,11).

Comment: Ok then i misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to find all combinations of ranges. Then you can transform them to sets and calculate the intersection:

```
import itertools


limits = [(3,10), (4,11), (2,6), (8,11), (9,11)]
ranges = [range(*lim) for lim in  limits]

results = []
for comb in itertools.combinations(ranges,3):
    intersection = set(comb[0]).intersection(comb[1])
    intersection = intersection.intersection(comb[2])
    if intersection and intersection not in results and\
       not any(map(intersection.issubset, results)):
        results = filter(lambda res: not intersection.issuperset(res),results)
        results.append(intersection)


result_limits =  [(res[0], res[-1]+1) for res in map(list,results)]
```

It should give you all 3-wise intersections

Comment: This comes close - it gives me `[set([4, 5]), set([8, 9]), set([9]), set([9, 10])]`.  There needs to be some work to combine overlaps, and there's a fence vs. fenceposts problem.

Comment: I see your point about the 3-wise intersections, but really it should be `[set([4, 6]), set([8, 9]), set([9]), set([9, 11])]`  You're missing the end integer of the ranges.

Comment: ok, one would have to add the following line:
`result = [(res[0], res[-1]+1) for res in map(list,results)]`

Comment: @dnalow this seems to work nicely but when I try to combine the overlaps with your list comprehension I get [(4, 6), (8, 10), (9, 10), (9, 11)] as the output. Is there any way to combine these ranges further?

Comment: OK i will add 2 lines to avoid the subsets

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course, solve this by brute-force checking all the combinations if you want.  If you need this algorithm to scale, though, you can do it in (pseudo) nlogn.  You can technically come up with a degenerate worst-case that's O(n**2), but whatchagonnado.

Basically, you sort the ranges, then for a given range you look to its *immediate left* to see that the bounds overlap, and if so you then look *right* to mark overlapping intervals as results.  Pseudocode (which is actually almost valid python, look at that):

```
ranges.sort()

for left_range, current_range, right_range in sliding_window(ranges, 3):
  if left_range.right < current_range.left:
    continue
  while right_range.left < min(left_range.right, current_range.right):
      results.append(overlap(left_range, right_range))
      right_range = right_range.next
  #Before moving on to the next node, extend the current_range's right bound
  #to be the longer of (left_range.right, current_range.right)
  #This makes sense if you think about it.
  current_range.right = max(left_range.right, current_range.right)

merge_overlapping(results)
```

(you also need to merge some possibly-overlapping ranges at the end, this is another nlogn operation - though n will usually be much smaller there.  I won't discuss the code for that, but it's similar in approach to the above, involving a sort-then-merge.  [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679638/merging-a-list-of-time-range-tuples-that-have-overlapping-time-ranges).)