# interval overlap size

Tags: python, math, intervals

what is the most concise way in Python to compute interval overlap size?

`overlap([a, b], [c, d])` should return 0 if intervals are identical, N when they overlap but not identical (where N is overlap) and None if they are not overlapping.

thanks.

*edit*: `overlap` is misleading i mean the size by which the intervals are non-overlapping. so 0 is they are identical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953967/built-in-function-for-computing-overlap-in-python ?

Comment: Why would you want to return 0 if the intervals are identical? That seems inconsistent with returning N when the intervals overlap but aren't identical.

Comment: Please give an example with some overlap. It will clarify the question.

Comment: Please clear up if N is size of overlap or size of non-overlap.

Comment: What if the intervals touch, i.e. what should `overlap([1, 2], [2, 4])` return?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't get much more concise than the accepted answer in the question linked to by sjr, but:

```
def overlap(a,b,c,d):
    r = 0 if a==c and b==d else min(b,d)-max(a,c)
    if r>=0: return r
```

would also return 0 for identical intervals and None for non-overlapping intervals as required.

Comment: 0 should be returned for identical intervals, not `None`. Also, your function, as written, will return `None` for any input.